# QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLV2_client_method

Tags: qt, client-server, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver, qsslsocket

I have created a sslclient and sslserver using QSslSocket in Qt 5.4.1 in debian wheezy. When I run the program they dont work at all. After debuging my code I saw when it try to create a new object from `QSslSocket` it return this error (`cannot resolve SSLV2_client_method`) in constractor.

this is block of my code:

```
SSlClient::SSlClient(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    client = new QSslSocket(this);
    client->setProtocol(QSsl::SslV3);

    connect(client, SIGNAL(encrypted()), this, SLOT(startTransfer()));
    connect(client, SIGNAL(encryptedBytesWritten(qint64)), this, SLOT(byteWritten()));


}
```

Comment: Have you installed OpenSSL on your system?

Comment: Yes i have installed openssl 1.0.1

Comment: Which operating system are you on?

Comment: I have debian wheezy on my system

Comment: Some Linux distributions configure SSL2 out of OpenSSL, because they think it's not secure. May be that's the reason of the warning. Try to install another version of OpenSSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has solved by compiling openssl as shared library.

Comment: Instructions how to do this would be great!

Comment: Just try to compile openssl on your system. Instruction for do this published over the internet.

Comment: @emolaus, [Installing Qt 5.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 - throws qt.network.ssl error on terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/711863/22704)